# MySql FOREIGN KEY Constraints, error 1005

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, innodb, foreign-key-relationship

I can [see](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) that there are constraints problems, but what would be the correct way to create a foreign key here?

```
mysql> 
mysql> show tables;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_nntp |
+----------------+
| articles       |
| newsgroups     |
+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> describe newsgroups;
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| newsgroup | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> describe articles;
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| subject      | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| content      | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| number       | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sent         | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| header_id    | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| newsgroup_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> ALTER TABLE articles ADD FOREIGN KEY (newsgroup_id) REFERENCES newsgroup(id);
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'nntp.#sql-3bf_9a' (errno: 150)
mysql>
```

Both tables use innodb.

the MySql Query browser generates:

```
ALTER TABLE `nntp`.`articles` ADD CONSTRAINT `new_fk_constraint` FOREIGN KEY `new_fk_constraint` (`newsgroup_id`)
    REFERENCES `newsgroups` (`id`)
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE SET NULL;
```

which results in the same error.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
ALTER TABLE articles
ADD FOREIGN KEY
newsgroup_fk (newsgroup_id)
REFERENCES newsgroups (id)
```

to add a foreign key from `articles` to `newsgroups`.

Comment: Thanks.  Followup question: why does the GUI generated code (see updated question) not work?  It gives the same error number.

Comment: I think it is because of the `on ... set NULL`. Your `newsgroup_id` is defined as `not null`. And the foreign key would set it to `null` if it gets deleted in the `newsgroups` table. That collides. You can replace `set null` with `cascade` to delete articles when the newsgroup gets deleted. or use `no action` to do nothing. It is up to you.